# no values saved in my database records

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to implement TSP in my project. Firstly, I've clustered students and then I've compute the real distance between school and each student then I've compute the real distance of the rout  in each cluster starting from the nearest  student to the school then the second nearest and so on . 
I want to improve the solution by applying student exchange algorithm that I can reduce the cost of the path, but it doesn't work! It doesn't store the values in the database also, It doesn't show any error message!! 
Can somebody help me pleaaaaaas 

here is my code:

```
SqlCommand l = new SqlCommand("Select TotalDistance FROM Bus WHERE B_ID = @BID");
l.Connection = cn;
l.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", currentB_ID);
double totDis = Convert.ToDouble(l.ExecuteScalar());
SqlCommand qryDis = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Bus SET BestDistance = (@d) WHERE B_ID = @BID");
qryDis.Connection = cn;
qryDis.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", currentB_ID);
qryDis.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", (totDis+Reduction));
qryDis.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: try to put a break point around qryDis.Connect=cn; then grab the value of qryDis, and test if the query works fine in Management studio express or other tool u r using

Comment: also call qryDis.prepare(); before executing.